# how can i loop this simulation1000 times and make one of the column together to be a matrix?

Tags: r, loops, simulation

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

# create a tibble with an id column for each simulation and x wrapped in list()
sim <- tibble(id = 1:1000,
               x = list(rbinom(1000,1,0.5))) %>% 
# to generate z, pr, y, k use map and map2 from the purrr package to loop over the list column x
# `~ ... ` is similar to `function(.x) {...}`
# `.x` represents the variable you are using map on
          mutate(z  = map(x, ~ log(1.3) * .x), 
                 pr = map(z, ~ 1 / (1 + exp(-.x))),
                 y  = map(pr, ~ rbinom(1000, 1, .x)),
                 k  = map2(x, y, ~ glm(.y ~ .x, family="binomial")),
# use broom::tidy to get the model summary in form of a tibble
                 sum = map(k, broom::tidy)) %>% 
# select id and sum and unnest the tibbles
  select(id, sum) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(sum)) %>% 
simAll <- sim %>% 
  filter(term !="(Intercept)")
```

simAll is like:

```
   id  term  estimate       std.error   statistic   p.value
1   1   .x  0.4058039189    0.1275272   3.182096892 1.462129e-03
2   2   .x  0.2515178701    0.1276719   1.970033693 4.883451e-02
3   3   .x  0.2464097082    0.1274321   1.933654251 5.315565e-02
4   4   .x  0.2308803864    0.1273598   1.812819663 6.985964e-02
5   5   .x  0.3029238760    0.1271623   2.382182816 1.721035e-02
6   6   .x  0.2452264719    0.1270829   1.929657417 5.364930e-02
7   7   .x  0.2390919312    0.1270123   1.882430831 5.977754e-02
8   8   .x  0.2437134055    0.1271373   1.916930426 5.524677e-02
9   9   .x  0.4372744410    0.1274612   3.430646232 6.021453e-04
10  10  .x  0.2915176118    0.1272609   2.290708545 2.198028e-02
11  11  .x  0.3373491310    0.1271283   2.653612132 7.963531e-03
12  12  .x  0.1991820874    0.1269380   1.569128570 1.166180e-01
13  13  .x  0.3437529981    0.1272502   2.701394595 6.904936e-03
14  14  .x  0.2229632179    0.1269851   1.755822253 7.911876e-02
15  15  .x  0.2606269011    0.1271385   2.049944533 4.036984e-02
Showing 1 to 15 of 1,000 entries, 6 total columns
```

The question here is that the estimate column here is the value of x, I want to have 1000 similar tables like simALL (like repeat the whole simulation 1000 times), and then I will have 1000 * 1000 x, I want to make them be a matrix (1000 * 1000), what should I do?

Comment: Just to confirm, should your output matrix only contain the estimate?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly.  Could you just run:  

`ids <- tibble(id = rep(1:1000,1000)) %>% arrange(id)`  

`new_simAll <- as.matrix(left_join(ids, simAll))`

Comment: @nico yes！You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function for the code that you want to repeat and return only the `estimate` column since that is the only information you need.

```
library(tidyverse)
run_fun <- function() {

sim <- tibble(id = 1:1000,
              x = list(rbinom(1000,1,0.5))) %>% 
          mutate(z  = map(x, ~ log(1.3) * .x), 
                 pr = map(z, ~ 1 / (1 + exp(-.x))),
                 y  = map(pr, ~ rbinom(1000, 1, .x)),
                 k  = map2(x, y, ~ glm(.y ~ .x, family="binomial")),
                 sum = map(k, broom::tidy)) %>%
           select(id, sum) %>% 
           unnest(cols = c(sum)) %>%
           filter(term !="(Intercept)") %>% 
           pull(estimate)
  return(sim)
}
```

You can call this function `n` times :

```
data <- replicate(1000, run_fun())
```

Comment: Thanks!! I think it should work, but it really needs a lot of time to run it. (Since needs to simulate 1000 times), Like is there any other way I can do this quicker?

Comment: Few things I can think of. Since `x = list(rbinom(1000,1,0.5)))` is same for all the rows, we can avoid using `map` for `z` and `pr` which would also be same. This might help to speedup the process.

Comment: WOW! You are really clever! Thanks!